# Вывод без буферизации

Tags: php, ajax, сокет

Есть удаленный скрипт обновления цен на сайте.
Скрипт выполняется примерно 5-7 мин.
Я хочу чтобы результат выполнения скрипта сразу выводилось в браузере.
Никакими стандартными средствами я не смог отключить буферизацию вывода.
Через файл(запись в файл и аяксом доставать результат ) не получается, аякс запрос все равно ожидает окончания работы скрипта, только если с разных браузеров. Хочу попробовать реализовать это дело через web-socket. Но вот не могу понять как. Подтолкните пожалуйста в нужную сторону... Или если есть еще какие-нибудь варианты...

Comment: http://www.php.su/flush

Comment: Никакими стандартными средствами я не смог отключить буферизацию вывода.

Comment: Там ещё описание есть, что может использовать свою буферизацию.

Comment: Как отключить буферизацию в браузере?

Comment: В браузере - никак. По крайней мере, не с сайта.

Comment: Попробуй создать приложение, которое читает данные и сразу выводит, т. е. гарантированно без буфера и обратиться с его помощью к своей странице - тогда точно определишь, проблема на сервере или на клиенте.

Comment: Через терминал(консоль) все работает как надо. Вопрос в том как это реализовать в браузере?

Comment: У вас используется GZIP в nginx или Apache?

Answer (score 1):

Запрос XMLHTTPRequest или по другому Ajax, регулярно отчитывается о своем состоянии через вызов функции onreadystatechange. Состояние под номером 4 означает конец выполнения и все данные получены, поэтому функция-обработчик при каждом вызове проверяет - не настало ли это состояние. Только после получения всех данных, будет вызвана окончательная функция обработки запроса.

Вообще, список состояний readyState такой:

```
0 - Unitialized
1 - Loading
2 - Loaded
3 - Interactive
4 - Complete
```

Состояния 0-2 вообще не используются.

Вызов функции с состоянием Interactive в теории должен происходить каждый раз при получении очередной порции данных от сервера. Это могло бы быть удобным для обработки ответа по частям, но Internet Explorer не дает доступа к уже полученной части ответа.

Firefox дает такой доступ, но для обработки запроса по частям состояние Interactive все равно использовать неудобно из-за сложностей обнаружения ошибок соединения. Поэтому Interactive тоже не используется.

На практике используется только последнее, Complete. Это и есть та ваша самая "буферизация", которая на самом деле является просто вынужденным механизмом работы Ajax. Пока все данные не получены, ничего обработать частично не получится.

---

Что делать?

Либо вы используете насильную загрузку по частям: то есть получаете сначала общее количество данных и потом уже несколькими отдельными запросами запрашиваете данные порциями, либо используете сокеты.

Найти информацию по использованию сокетов и поведения, которое в браузере Вас интересует, можно через волшебное слово Comet. Ну или тут поискать [learn.javascript.ru - ajax и comet](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax).

Answer (score 0):

В общем решил все таки через файл. Но я не мог понять почему аjax запрос становился в очередь на сервере, и дожидался пока не закончит работу скрипт который длился 5-7 мин. Перед тем как запускать "долгий" скрипт, я принудительно закрывал соединение с пользователем, только после этого ajax запросы стали проходить без очереди.
Входе работы долгого скрипта, промежуточные результаты записывал в файл. А ежесекундные ajax запросы доставали их из файла, и выводили в браузер.
Возможно это костыли, но сменить настройки на удаленном хостинге я не могу, а подключать доп. библиотеки для работы с сокетами я не стал.